# Going over an MCQ exam we got not sure why this function prototype would fail

Tags: c++

Hi all took a recent MCQ going over the answers I got wrong.

A function getSum is dened to compute the sum of the values in a double array a[] of size
size, that are bigger than a given input value threshold. The following shows four prototype denitions, along with how the function is called from main. Choose the option which will not compile because the function is being called incorrectly according to its prototype.

```
(c)
double getSum(const double a[], int size, double& threshold);


int main()
{
double a[5]=f10.0,11.0,9.9,12.0, 13.6g;

double sum;

sum=getSum(a, 5, 10.0);
```

Why will this function prototype fail?

Answer (score 3):

It will fail due to attempt to pass non const temporary reference, in 3rd param.
[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c7d11a94da2f3f8173b047799a5f3f80-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba) you can see compiler output.